# Gson include fields and exclude strategy on list of object

Tags: java, json, spring, gson

I have GSon serializer for main object, something like this:

```
Class A {
    String field1;
    String field2;
    List<B> listB;
}
```

and another class as:

```
Class B {
    String field3;
    int field4;
    List<Object> listO;
}
```

I want to perform 2 operations (separately) as given below:
1. In GSon exclude strategy, I want to remove B.field4 and include all remaining fields.
2. In serialization, I want to include B.field4 only, all other fields should be wiped out.

With existing code, I am able to remove fields with simple identifier like field4 but the problem is it will remove field4 from all other nested objects(is there is any).

So I want to include & exclude fields based on nested identifir like B.field4 or B.C.field 5 for example.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

User `Gson's` [@Expose](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html) annotations.

```
Class B {

    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = true)
    String field3;

    @Expose(serialize = true, deserialize = false)
    int field4;

    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = true)
    List<Object> listO;
}
```

Adjust serialize / deserialize value as per your need.

Comment: cannot do changes by adding annotations in entity classes as they are designed by someone else. I just want to modify result and return back to user. I would prefer some tweak using exclude strategy, if any.